# How to find vector such that $\|u\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

How  to   find a  vector  such  that $\|u\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}=1$   where  $\Omega$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I need  explict  form in order to  make some calculus
thanks  for  suggestions

Comment: What is $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and what is $\lVert . \rVert_{H_0^1 (\Omega)}$?

Comment: That is a very standard notation for Sobolev space and Sobolev norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a nonzero function $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and define $u = \dfrac{v}{\|v\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}}$.

Added on edit: If $\Omega = B(0,1)$ you can take $v(x) = 1 - |x|$. More generally, if $B(x_0,\epsilon) \subset \Omega$ you can take $$v(x) = \left(1 - \dfrac{|x - x_0|}{\epsilon}\right) \chi_{B(x_0,\epsilon)}(x).$$

Comment: I need  explict  form in order to  make some calculus

Comment: Umberto P. Thanks so  much

Comment: in there no  a problem in the boundary de $B(x_0,\epsilon)$ ?   exists weak derivate  in those points ?

Comment: $v(x) = 0$ if $x \in \partial B(x_0,\epsilon)$.